# What's the meaning of conglomerate prayer?

Tags: american-english, spoken-english

What's the meaning of this? Or what is the joint prayer that muslims/ Christians/Jews in their respective worship places do called? E.g we need to do a conglomerate prayer to please God?

Comment: I've never heard the phrase before.  Can you give us the context where you saw it?

Answer (score 2):

You may be thinking of [*corporate prayer*](http://www.allaboutprayer.org/corporate-prayer.htm):

> Corporate prayer is the term used to describe praying together with other people—in small groups or in larger bodies of people.

AllAboutPrayer.org

The term is not restricted to American English.

Answer (score 1):

You may be thinking of [congregational prayer](http://www.living-prayers.com/events/congregational_prayer.html)

Where a single prayer is said for the entire gathering of people.